# How to get component from HTML code in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Sorry for my question, I am new in React.js learning.
At the moment I try to show OL maps using its API in my code. Here I have three files, but I get empty page in my browser. Tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import {OSM} from 'ol/source';

window.onload = init;

function init() {
  let map = new Map({
    layers: [new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
}
```

**Map.js**

```
import {Component} from 'react';

    class Map extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
              // ???
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with React? There's no sign of React anywhere in that code.

Comment: Open the Console of the browser's developer tools. There should be at least one error that makes it clear what one of your problems is.

Comment: Agree with Quentin, you haven't called `import React from 'react';` 

So your class Map extends Component won't really do anything as Component is short for React.Component.

Comment: Did you create these three files in a folder, then double click the HTML one to open it in a browser? That won't work anyway. You need a proper node/webpack environment to be able to use `import`.

Comment: EDITed: added import line into Map.js

Comment: Actually I need to show OL maps in a browser, but I have no idea how to connect files each with other

Comment: Like I said, what connects these files is webpack or other bundlers. It won't work without them. You need nodeJS, and you need to setup your package.json accordingly, like demonstrated [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html).

Comment: If you are new to react then I suggest you start with their getting started guide(s). They can explain much more than comments here can. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-for-the-tutorial

Comment: And when you have a basic React app [up and running](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#create-react-app--) you might want to use [this](https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers) instead.

Comment: @ChrisG, I have got a React project already, I just want t add a map to my application (in one of my view pages that is Map.js), but I can't imagine how to do import to Map.js to show what actually .html and .js filesstore in the link you gave

Comment: You don't download the files and use them, you install the package: https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers#install

Comment: @ChrisG sorry, it seems that I can't understand you

FIrst, I used install like "npm install ol" as well as "npm install react-openlayers --save-dev" right now

So, what should be done then?

Comment: I know this can be confusing, but just because there's an npm package doesn't mean it's compatible with React. The `ol` package is for npm based web development, not React. If you want to use openlayers in a React app, use the wrapper instead. `npm install react-openlayers`. ... and next, why not look at the [usage example directly below](https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers#usage)?

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sun-exww1

Comment: @ChrisG thank you ery much. And what is the difference between your example and this one? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208910/discussion-between-robert-gurjiev-and-chris-g).